# Why my CreateAPIView does not show Product and store category field?

Tags: python, django, api, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am designing an API for listing stores and create store. I could list store but while designing for creating store I am not getting product and store category field inspite of calling all Product and Store category serializer in Store Serializer.

**My shortened models look like**

```
class Merchant(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    phone = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True,blank=True)

class Store(models.Model):
    merchant = models.ForeignKey(Merchant)
    name_of_legal_entity = models.CharField(max_length=250)

class Product(models.Model):
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store)
    image = models.ForeignKey('ProductImage',blank=True,null=True)
    name_of_product = models.CharField(max_length=120)

class ProductImage(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/images/')

class StoreCategory(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product,null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="store_category")
    store_category = models.CharField(choices=STORE_CATEGORIES, default='GROCERY', max_length=10)
```

**Serializer.py**

```
class ProductImageSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ProductImage
        fields  =   ( 'id','imageName', )

class ProductSerializers(ModelSerializer):
    image = ProductImageSerializer(many=False,read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields=('id','image','name_of_product','description','price','active',)

class StoreCategorySerializer(ModelSerializer):
    product = ProductSerializers(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = StoreCategory

class StoreSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    # url = HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='stores_detail_api')
    store_categories = StoreCategorySerializer(many=True) 
    merchant = MerchantSerializer(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Store
        fields=("id",
                "merchant",
                "store_categories",
                "name_of_legal_entity",
                "pan_number",
                "registered_office_address",
                "name_of_store",
                )
```

**Views.py**

```
class StoreCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Store.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StoreSerializer
    parser_classes = (FormParser,MultiPartParser,)

    def put(self, request, filename, format=None):
        print('first put works')
        file_obj = request.data['file']
        print ('file_obj',file_obj)
        return Response(status=204)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        print('then perform works')
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

Here is the screenshot of how it looks

[image]

Why it is not showing Merchant, Product and Store Category in the form?

Comment: if your merchant id is auto increment or auto generated then it is normal that it is not there.

Comment: my merchant model looks like this class Merchant(models.Model):
 user = models.ForeignKey(User)
 phone = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True,blank=True)

Comment: @JustinM.Ucar i have updated my question with Merchant model. Its not auto increment, it contains user and user address, phone number etc.

Comment: Remove `read_only=True` from the serializers

Comment: did it work after removing them?

Comment: Yes only for Merchant . It is not showing product and ProductSerializer is being called inside StoreCategorySerializer.

Comment: It is called inside StoreCategorySerializer but not inside StoreSerializer. So i think i have to create new serializer for POST because if i remove many=True it wont work for listing and for POST correct input boxes are rendered by it.

Comment: I see. I did not notice it at first. Should we post is as an answer?

Comment: Yes sure. But one out of this question scope, i would like to ask why after posting i get "username": [
                "A user with that username already exists."
            ]

Comment: that is because serializer is trying to create a user entry along with merchant as well. May be you should create an Inline model for merchant that excludes user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `read_only=True` from the serializers that you wanna create entry of.
Like:

```
product = ProductSerializers(read_only=True)
```

should be

```
product = ProductSerializers()
```

`read_only` will prevent it from written therefore i wont be in the outcome.